# flie write not working if program run on boot

Tags: c, linux, file-io

Here is the simple program to create and write a file. It work if run normally but not able to create file if execute on boot up (add /home/root/a.out in /etc/rc.local).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        FILE *fp=fopen("dummy","w");
        fprintf(fp,"hello world\n");
        printf("fp=%d\n",fp);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that it is actually being run on boot? If yes, have you checked what directory it is run in, e.g., is the file in `/`? Is the filesystem mounted rw?

Comment: What are your file's permissions?

Comment: Are you running it after the filesystems are mounted?

Comment: The program needs more error checking. For example, after `FILE *fp=fopen("dummy", "w");`, add `if (fp == NULL) {` `perror("dummy");` `return 1;` `}`.

Comment: `printf("fp=%d\n",fp);` is wrong because `fp` is a pointer. I suggest `printf("fp=%p\n", (void *)fp);`.

Comment: @Arkku I'm sure it is running since I wrote other program and configure on boot execution in the same way. How do I know if filesystem mounted in rw?

Comment: Try redirecting stderr to a file in /tmp and print any error that occurs to stderr

Comment: I just figure out the problem is I didn't use absolute directory in fopen and I thought the file wasn't created... Thanks every one.